# How do I toggle highlighting of FIXME/TODO/XXX in Vim?

Tags: vim, latex

I'm using Vim to edit LaTeX files and it used to automatically highlight these words and was a great help. I also have `:set spell` to highlight spelling mistakes and I had added `TODO`, `FIXME` and `XXX` to the spell-good list (`zg`). Recently, I did something I can't recall/reproduce and broke this. I still get LaTeX keywords like `begin`, `section`, etc. highlighted, but not these ones.

Searching online only leads to people complaining about these words being highlighted and they turn it off by issuing `:syntax clear Todo`. I have the exact opposite issue—I want it turned back on. Can someone clue me on how to proceed?

Comment: It would help if you detailed how you did it first.

Comment: I didn't have to do anything. The default behavior in vim was to highlight these marker words. And that's also the reason why I don't know how it got turned off.

Comment: Then show us your vimrc and tell us what plugins you have.

Comment: Here's my vimrc: http://pastebin.com/p6y887vD Nothing fancy...

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709965/vim-highlight-the-word-todo-for-every-filetype

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the "Todo" syntax/highlight group is cleared somewhere in your vimrc. I don't see any issues with the vimrc that you linked in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709114/how-do-i-toggle-highlighting-of-fixme-todo-xxx-in-vim#comment15534718_11709114), but I would guess that line which says `runtime! archlinux.vim` might be the culprit. Try commenting out that line, and see if it works.

It may not be desired to comment out that line. If that is the case, add this to the end of your vimrc:

```
augroup vimrc_todo
    au!
    au Syntax * syn match MyTodo /\v<(FIXME|TODO|XXX)/
          \ containedin=.*Comment,vimCommentTitle
augroup END
hi def link MyTodo Todo
```