# Vim : Highlight the word TODO for every filetype

Tags: vim, editor, syntax-highlighting

I would like to highlight the word TODO in vim, no matter what file is edited (code or normal text). It currently works for many different languages (for example, TODO is highlighted in C/Java comments by default), but I use vim for non-code text files and I would like to see the TODOs highlighted for them too.

What is the easiest way to do that ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Highlighting TODO for every filetype and without possibly breaking other syntax rules can be done only by using `:match`/`matchadd()`:

```
augroup HiglightTODO
    autocmd!
    autocmd WinEnter,VimEnter * :silent! call matchadd('Todo', 'TODO', -1)
augroup END
```

Comment: Great, it works perfectly. And after a look into the matchadd() help, I discovered that highlighting other words such as FIXME was as easy as changing the `'TODO'` into a more complex pattern, such as `'\(TODO\)\|\(FIXME\)'`. Thank you very much !

Comment: @user1536048 You don’t need `\(...\)` in such simple cases: `TODO\|FIXME` is enough.